# What is the size denomination in os.path.size()? - python

Tags: python, file, path, operating-system, size

`os.path.getsize()` can be used to get the size of file.

But what does the number represent:

- bytes?
- bits?
- megabytes?

Also, i'm sure there's some rounding off involved because it always return an integer, **does it round up or round down?**

Comment: The documentation has answers. Bytes need not be rounded.

Comment: There is no `os.path.size()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? (from [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize))

```
"""
os.path.getsize(path)
Return the size, in bytes, of path. Raise os.error if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

It returns the size in bytes, as shown in the official Python documentation found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)